# How to Create a Radius server that support PEAP Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, radius

I want to create a radius server that support PEAP (type 25 - PEAP with EAP-TLS )
I have sufficient information and know every thing about Radius Packets And PEAP Packets format ( RFC 2865 radius)
the only difficult part of my project is TLS message inside EAP packet.
according to RFC 2246 (TLS 1.0) I need some tools that help me creating phase 1 of PEAP Protocol.
in PEAP phase 1 a TLS channel ( inside radius packet and inside EAP message attribute - UDP ) is stablished . other data in phase 2 is sent through that tls channel .
since PEAP is done in 2 phases, phase 1 is my major problem
bellow tools didn't help me :

1- System.Net.Security.SslStream class . (this works over TCP whereas radius works over UDP ) .

2- secureBlackbox DTLS classes . (this is a high level DLL and doesn't allow me to change data before TLS handshake process . editting data which are received from client before any process of TLS protocol is needed, because received data is a radius packet . Firstly I have to extract the TLS message from it . then send it as a proxy . but secureBlackBox classes doesn't allow me to change data.)

3- FreeRadius project ( www.freeradius.org )
this project has written in C language and is difficult for me to convert it to C# .

would you please help me to establish TLS channel in my radius packet ?
thank you in advance for your time and consideration .

Comment: You could always use platform invoke to call FreeRADIUS's libeap :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET library which you can download for free named nRadius. I haven't used it though, I've only used freeradius via PInvoke.

http://nradius.nw-network.com/web/?page_id=19
http://www.heise.de/download/nradius-1156905.html

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a radius server using C#. I don't think the sslstream class with dotnet will work. Unless you develop a BIO as a interpreter and use the sslstream class, radius with peap work under eap. Just the record layer data is encrypted, have to do all the handshaking and encrypting/decrypting.

I'm not sure about the dtls, but probably doesn't work too, because later on you'll need some data from the handshake process to calculate the mppe key etc.